# Android Google Maps URL query - placing marker while offline

Tags: java, android, google-maps, url, location

I'm launching the following intent from my Android app, using Google's [published format for map URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#search-action):

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=51.196327,-7.325649")));
```

All I want to do is place a marker on the map at the queried location. It works fine when I'm online, but if I go offline, all I get is a *Can't connect* message. Even if I dismiss the message, the marker won't appear. This even happens if I download offline maps for the area I'm marking.

The offline marker thing is a big part of my app, so I'd love to know if there's a way to place pins via URL even if the map below can't load? If there's a way to just place a marker and bypass any local searching, that would be ideal. At the moment, Maps insists on searching for stuff nearby which isn't required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually possible to place and show a marker in google maps with the mobile offline.

You can do it using its [custom url scheme](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents):

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:51.196327,-7.325649?q=51.196327,-7.325649");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(mapIntent);
}
```

after `geo:` you set the center coordinates and then the `q` parameter is to perform a search (like the one you were doing) and if you set a coordinate as a search parameter it will show a marker in there.

And the same example in **kotlin**:

```
val gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:51.196327,-7.325649?q=51.196327,-7.325649")
val mapIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri)
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps")
if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
    startActivity(mapIntent)
}
```

You could provide an else condition to do something in case the google maps app is not installed on that device.

Comment: I just tried the `geo:` URL and it works - thanks! Also seen it in some different examples so it looks like a good way to go.